# fetch data from database and use it in drag n drop

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have created a page for drag n drop in which the elements are cloned in draggable space and are then stored in database.I'm storing the id,height,width,x_pos,y_pos. all this work is done in .js file. How should I retrieve the data in javascript page n check whether element was dropped previously. When I reload page,its starts from the beginning, means have to drag the element. Can anyone give some idea.

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function () {


    var x = null;

    //Make element draggable
    $(".drag").draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        cursor: 'move',
        tolerance: 'fit'
    });
    var i=1,j=0;
    var x1,x2,y1,y2;
    var sf=pf;                     //this is the scalig factor
    var tmp;
    var fty=ft;                     // this is the floor_type i'm getting from php page
    var fd=fid;
    $("#droppable").droppable({

      drop: function(e, ui) {

          var attr=ui.helper.attr('id');
         // document.write(attr);
          if(typeof attr == typeof undefined || attr == false)
          {
        ui.helper.attr('id',"id"+i);
          }
        x = ui.helper.clone().bind("click",'img',function(){
        alert("clicked"+ ui.helper.attr('id') );
        var cor=window.prompt("Enter coordinates width*height");
        tmp=ui.helper.attr('id');
        //document.write("position");
        var leftpos=($(this).offset().left) - 210;
        var toppos=($(this).offset().top);
        //document.write("position" + leftpos+"   " + toppos);
        var c=cor.split("*");

        var wt=c[0];
        var ht=c[1];
        var w=wt*sf;
        var h=ht*sf;

        $(this).width(w);
    $(this).height(h);
        var leftpos=($(this).offset().left)-241;
        var toppos=($(this).offset().top);
        alert("position"+ leftpos + toppos);
        window.location.href="roomdata.php?id="+tmp+"&"+"width="+w+"&"+"height="+h+"&"+"leftpos="+leftpos+"&"+"toppos="+toppos+"&"+"floor_type="+fty+"&"+"floor_id="+fd;
        });
                x.draggable({

                helper: 'original',
                containment: '#droppable',
                tolerance: 'fit'
            }); 


            x.appendTo('#droppable');
            ui.helper.remove();
             i++;
       }

    });

    });

//ROOMDATA.PHP

         <?php
          include("config.php");

     $rid=$_GET['id'];
     $wth=$_GET['width'];
     $hgt=$_GET['height'];
     $lp=$_GET['leftpos'];
     $tp=$_GET['toppos'];
     $ft=$_GET['floor_type'];
      $fid=$_GET['floor_id'];

       //echo "hello". $rid."  ".$wth."  ".$hgt."  ".$lp."  ".$tp."  ".$ft." "; 

         $sql="Insert into room_m(floor_id,room_as_id,width,height,start_x,start_y)values('".$fid."','".$rid."','".$wth."','".$hgt."','".$lp."','".$tp."')";
          $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

          if($result)
           {
            //echo "done";
            header("location:rooms.php");
           }
         else
            echo "error";
      ?>
```

here is the code for html side.I'm using php also for getting the data from another page i.e floor id and then generating a floor on the basis of the data which I get.
I'm also using session as if I have selected floor id=0 then that will remain same for the time being until the user finishes adding rooms to the floor.
If its new that it will generate new rooms,If it is already there then it will get data from the database and then show the div tag.But I don't know how to display the div tag,I'm getting the data from database.

```
  <html>


    <head>
        <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
           google.load("jquery", "1.6.3");
           google.load("jqueryui", "1.8.16");
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jqueryui1.css"/>

        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>-->
        <script src="dragndrop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqueryui-ruler/css/jquery.ui.ruler.css">
    <script src="external/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="external/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jqueryui-ruler/js/jquery.ui.ruler.js"></script>
     <script language="JavaScript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#droppable').ruler();
        });

    </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .col{
    float:left;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#col1{
    width:200px;
    height:500px;
    border:1px solid black;

}

.drag{
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid black;
    height:40px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:red;
    background-image:url(restaurant/8793_532242100147879_270911928_n.jpg);
}

#droppable{
 padding-top:18px;
 padding-left:18px;
 padding-right:20px;
    border:1px solid black;
    }

        </style>
            </head>

  <body>

    <?php
    require("config.php");
     $id=$_SESSION['restid']; 
    if(isset($_SESSION['ft'])){
    $ft=$_SESSION['ft'];
    $query="select floor_id,width,height from floor_m where floor_type='".$ft."' and rest_id='".$id."'";
    $res1=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $row1=mysqli_fetch_row($res1);
    $fd=$row1[0];
    $w=$row1[1];
    $h=$row1[2];
    echo $fd;
    $query2="select room_as_id,width,height,start_x,start_y from room_m where floor_id='".$fd."'";
    $res2=mysqli_query($con,$query2);
    $row2=mysqli_fetch_row($res2);
    $rai=$row2[0];
    $ww=$row2[1];
    $hh=$row2[2];
    $xx=$row2[3];
    $yy=$row2[4];
    echo $rai,$ww,$hh,$xx,$yy;
    $wd=500/$w;
    $_SESSION['wd']=$wd;
    $_SESSION['ft']=$ft;
    $_SESSION['fid']=$fd;
    echo '<script>var pf = '.json_encode($_SESSION['wd']).';
    var ft='.json_encode($_SESSION['ft']).';
    var fid='.json_encode($_SESSION['fid']).';</script>'; 
    $ht=$h*$wd;

    }
    else{
        $ft=$_POST['fl_type'];

    //echo $ft;


    $sql="select width,height,floor_id from floor_m where floor_type='".$ft."' and rest_id='".$id."'";
    //echo $sql;
    $res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_row($res);
    $w=$row[0];
    $h=$row[1];
    $fid=$row[2];
    $wd=500/$w;
    $_SESSION['wd']=$wd;
    $_SESSION['ft']=$ft;
    $_SESSION['fid']=$fid;
    echo '<script>var pf = '.json_encode($_SESSION['wd']).';
    var ft='.json_encode($_SESSION['ft']).';
    var fid='.json_encode($_SESSION['fid']).';</script>'; 
    $ht=$h*$wd;
    }
    //echo $wd,$ht;
    ?>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class = "col" id="col1">
                <img src="" id="drag1" class="drag">                
            </div>
            <div class="col" id="droppable" style="width:500px;position:relative; height:<?php echo $ht;?>">

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: What does your `roomdata.php` look like?

Comment: @David Wyly I have edited the code.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to reproduce this on my local machine, and just realized I don't know your HTML structure for this to work. Could you include a working or stripped down sample of the HTML?

Comment: Added the html code.. @David Wyly

Answer (score 0):

You could create a controller PHP file (like an API endpoint) that the javascript can use to request database information from the PHP backend.

So for your PHP controller file, something like this:

```
// getRoom.php

// {include your database config here}

function fail($message = null,$code = 500) {
    http_response_code($code);
    exit($message);
}

function success($payload = null, $code = 200) {
    http_response_code($code);
    exit($payload);
}

if (!isset($_POST['room_id'])) {
    fail("'room_id' parameter must be in POST request",404);
}

$room_id = $_POST['room_id'];

// WARNING: you should be using prepared statements; this query is subject to SQL injection!
$sql = "SELECT * FROM room_m WHERE room_id = $room_id"; // just a guess
result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if (!$result) {
    fail("Could not find room $room_id",404);
}

$payload = json_encode($result);
success($payload);
```

Then, you can use a JQuery AJAX function to POST to this controller and receive a response that javascript can interpret; all without reloading the page:

```
function getRoom(room_id) {
    data = {
        'room_id': room_id
    };
    $.post(
        'getRoom.php',
        data
    ).done(
        function (data) {
            // parse the JSON response
            var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

            // log it in the console for debugging purposes
            console.log(response);

            // call a function that sets the dimensions for the room
            setDimensions(response);
        }
    ).fail(
        function (xhr) {
            // log it in the console for debugging purposes
            console.log(xhr);

            // do something
        }
    );
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Let me know how it goes! Fortunately, I've had some code handy for an application that does something very similar. Calling a backend API controller is a very good pattern to use when you want to dynamically get database information into your javascript frontend, all without reloading the page.

Comment: I just want to know how should I display the div tag whose data I get from the database, after all this process.